# Is it possible to use suPHP to return an entire HTML file?

Tags: php, html, suphp

[For the sake of argument](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11009/how-do-you-get-people-to-answer-the-question-rather-than-argue-the-premise), lets assume that I can't change my file permissions. Furthermore, assume all my `.html` files have the permission `0700` like so:

```
-rwx------ 1 user user 0 2012-01-09 19:50 aquinas.html
-rwx------ 1 user user 0 2012-01-09 19:50 daedalus.html
-rwx------ 1 user user 0 2012-01-09 19:50 helios.html
-rwx------ 1 user user 0 2012-01-09 19:50 icarus.html
-rwx------ 1 user user 0 2012-01-09 19:50 index.html
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 0 2012-01-09 19:52 require.php
```

Therefore I can't access my `index.html` file simply by typing `www.example.com/index.html` in my browser. What I can do, however, is set up a `require.php` file in the main web folder and set its permission to `0755`. Lets assume this `require.php` file finds the specified `.html` file and returns its full contents. Assume also that I have suPHP running. Then I could call `require.php` --as the owner of `require.php`-- fetch the contents of, for example, `index.html`, and pass it to the calling browser. I know `require.php` is capable of fetching the file contents serverside. What I want to know is whether it can return the contents as an html file for the browser to load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try this:

```
<?php // your require.php
echo file_get_contents('index.html');
exit();
```

Comment: yes that is what I am currently doing for `.js` files (via `xmlhttprequest` executed as javascript), my question is basically how I call it on the client? For example if clicking on a link takes you to `daedalus.html`, do I just instead call `require.php` with `daedalus.html` as an argument?